# jQuery Datepicker mark range

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have two datepickers applied to a div on my website to implement a date range. Now I want to highlight all dates in the calendar, which are in the selected range (e.g. applying a css class on them).

I found this:
[Select a Range of dates and Highlight in jQuery Datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918071/select-a-range-of-dates-and-highlight-in-jquery-datepicker)

But how can I insert all selected days in an array? Or is there even a better solution?

How can I manage this? I couldn't find a built-in solution of the datepicker plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is a old one but I needed the same functionality so here is how I did it in case someone needs it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery( "#start_date" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    rangeSelect:true,
    beforeShowDay: customRange,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        jQuery( "#end_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
jQuery( "#end_date" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    rangeSelect:true,
    beforeShowDay: customRange,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        jQuery( "#start_date" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
});
function customRange(date) {
    if(date >= jQuery('#start_date').datepicker('getDate') && date <= jQuery('#end_date').datepicker('getDate')) {
        return [true, 'highlight'];
    } else {
        return [true, ''];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" id="from">
<input type="text" id="to">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#to").datepicker();
    $("#from").datepicker().bind("change",function(){
        var minValue = $(this).val();
        minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", minValue);
        minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate()+1);
        $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minValue );
    })
});
</script>
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/dW4n8/2/

```
$("#input-service_date_leave, #input-service_date_return").datepicker({
        rangeSelect: true,
        beforeShow: customRange,
        onSelect: customRange,
    });

function customRange(input) {
    if (input.id == "input-service_date_leave") {

        $("#ui-datepicker-div td").die();

        if (selectedDate != null) {
            $('#input-service_date_return').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate).datepicker('refresh');
        }
    }
    if (input.id == "input-service_date_return") {

        $("#ui-datepicker-div td").live({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $(this).parent().addClass("finalRow");
                $(".finalRow").prevAll().find("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
                $(this).prevAll("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
           },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass("finalRow");
                $("#ui-datepicker-div td").removeClass("highlight");
            }
        });

        var selectedDate = $("#input-service_date_leave").datepicker("getDate");                
        if (selectedDate != null) {
            $('#input-service_date_return').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate).datepicker('refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant the following: I select for the "from date" 2013/01/01 and for the "to date" 2013/01/05, now I want to highlight (e.g. add a css class) to the dates: 2013/01/01, 2013/01/02...2013/01/05.

Comment: Thanks for your help! We're getting there, but it is unfortunately not exactly what i want. The user should select the first date, select the second date, and after that the range should have a red background. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dW4n8/81/ Now select your "from date" on the first calendar and your "to date" on the second calendar. After that the range should be red in both calendars. Do you know what I mean? Thank you very much!